# Error al crear un proyecto ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

Al tratar de crear un proyecto de aplicación web en asp.net core 2.2 me aparece el siguiente mensaje

> error NU1202: El paquete Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.2.0 no es compatible
>   con netcoreapp2.2 en 151 errores

soluciones que probé:

- Reinstalación del paquete
- Reinstalación del SDK 2.2
- Reinstalación de Visual studio

Comment: Solo ese mensaje recibes ? porque alli parece mencionar 151 errores, no creo que reinstalar paquetes, framework o el VS sea el camino. Si creas un proyecto en otra version del framework compila? que version de VS estas utilizando

Comment: Hola que version de VS estas usando? proba de instalarte VS2019 (el ultimo update) y la ultima version de dotnet 2.2. A veces algún update en particular rompe todo (o combinacion, tal update de VS no anda con tal minor fix del framework), pero por lo menos las ultimas versiones andan bien.

Answer (score 0):

Me ha pasado algo parecido.

Al final me di cuenta de que no se compilaba el proyecto porque le faltaba definir la url de los repositorios Nuget para que actualizase las dependencias.

Añade esto en la configuración de los paquetes Nugets:

[image: Nuget]